# Different decimal formats within same numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, decimalformat

I reshaped a 3D NumPy array to 2D using the reshape method by X1 = np.reshape(input,(500, 3*40)). Now the new 2D array has different formats such as,

few rows have the following format -

```
X1[8,:] has -

array([ 5557.,  2001.,  1434.,  1348.,   991.,  1240.,  1668.,  1093.,
        1680.,  1476.,  2521.,  1841.,  2443.,  2295.,  1911.,  2491., and so on .... ])
```

whereas few other rows have the following format -

```
X1[9,:] has -

array([3.69900e+04, 1.19090e+04, 1.12300e+04, 1.25170e+04, 6.91000e+03,
       7.24700e+03, 8.31800e+03, 6.31000e+03, 8.96700e+03, 7.18100e+03,
       1.03010e+04, 9.69800e+03, 1.29270e+04, 1.33140e+04, 1.00420e+04, and so on ... ])
```

Since they don't have the same format throughout, I am not sure if it will cause a problem during neural network model training. I am not sure how to maintain the same decimal format throughout the same NumPy array.

Comment: What do  you mean, "they don't have the same format"?  Do you have an array of floats, or of strings?  As far as I can see, you're worrying that the default display format will somehow affect the computational values -- in which case, you have the relationship backwards.

Comment: Yeahh I wanted them to have the same format.. And I was worried if it will impact the computation.

Comment: If you need to format the output presentation, then see various tutorials on Python output formatting.  The internal format is an ISO standard binary float representation.  Your values for computation are not affected by the output format.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't problem for You, because *5557.* and *1.03010e+04* are float both. The second number format ( scientific notation is only for show (print) the numbers ).

Remeber that numpy array has just one data tipe for all items in an array, you could get it with **array.dtype** attribute

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks for the explanation.